# Measures on infinite dimensional spaces?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, soft-question, definition

I am looking for a measures on an infinite dimensional space. In the process I came across the theorem structure theorem for Gaussian measure. The link for the theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_Gaussian_measures

As I understand I have no other option but to stick to Gaussian measure. I want to have an intuitive idea why only Gaussian measure ( I did not quite the understand the proof, too mathematical) is possible. Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are misreading the theorem. It says that a **Gaussian** measure on a Banach space is somehow realized by the "usual" Gaussian measure. It says nothing about other measures.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you for your comment. I thought so as it is written "abstract Wiener space construction is essentially the only way to obtain...". Is there 'non-probability" measure exist for infinite dimensional space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the space, measures may be fairly easy to come by. For example, if $B$ is any separable Banach space, let $\{a_n\}$ be a countable dense subset.  Then define, for any $E\subset B$,
$$\mu(E)=\sum_n 2^{-n}\,\delta_{a_n}(E),$$ where $\delta_{a_n}(E)=1$  if $a_n\in E$, and zero otherwise. Since weighted sums of measures are measures, $\mu$ is a probability measure on $B$.

Of course, any other set of weights may be used.

Comment: Is this a Dirac measure?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Each $\delta$ is a point measure. The sum is certainly not a point measure.